# Combobox funcion limpiar

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: muestra del error]
Tengo la funcion limpiar,pero no se que debo poner en las comillas o en lugar de setModel para que cuando realice la funcion el combobox se quede con la primera opcion(que serian estas lineas"-----")para indicar que no se ha seleccionado nada.
Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes Dubido, has el [**_Recorrido_**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer mas de como funciona el sitio. Ademas re recomiendo que leas [**_¿Como Preguntar?_**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para elaborar una pregunta de calidad y que sea mejor recibida. Por ejemplo poner una foto de tu código, es una muy mala practica.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

intenta con
`jcmbeditorial.setSelectedIndex(0);`

Comment: Hola Mario Catete, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla). Esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su longitud y contenido, y casi parece más un comentario que una respuesta. Lee [answer] y edita la publicación para mejorarla con las recomendaciones que encontrarás allí.